# Get visited edges in OrientDB's shortestPath()

Tags: java, graph-theory, orientdb, graph-databases

I am new to OrientDB and I want to use the new shortestPath() method to get the edges that are between two vertices.

What I do is:

```
OSQLSynchQuery<T> sql = new OSQLSynchQuery<T>("select shortestpath(" + firstVertex + ", " + secondVertex + ").asString()");

List<ODocument> execute = db.query(sql);
```

and what I can only get is `[#-2:1{shortestpath:[#8:1, #8:3]} v0]`.

So, I wanted to know how could I extract the edges (well, only one edge in this case, because these two vertices are directly connected) from this output or from the output that I get without `asString()`:

```
[#-2:1{shortestpath:[2]} v0]
```

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB has collection and map types. To make a collection the result set (what you're interested) you've to flatten it:

```
select flatten( shortestpath(" + firstVertex + ", " + secondVertex + ") )
```

To get the edges outgoing edges there are so many ways. Below a few of them:

```
select vertices.out from (
   select flatten( shortestpath(" + firstVertex + ", " + secondVertex + ") ) as vertices
)
```

Or also:

```
select flatten( shortestpath(" + firstVertex + ", " + secondVertex + ").out )
```

Comment: I still cannot get the edge/s. I get now `[#-2:0 v0]`

Comment: Could it be because of using `db.query(sql)`? With it I can only get an ArrayList and not a Map. If it is because of this, what else could I use to execute an sql query in Java?

Comment: You've to cross the edges. There are several ways. I change my answer to support it

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them worked for me. Using the first way I got `[#-2:1 v0]` and with the second I got `[#-2:0 v0]`. Maybe I should use `doc.field("some_field");` for each `ODocument doc` in `List<ODocument> execute` to be able to see the results. If it is the case, which is the "some_field" I should use?

Comment: What release are you using? I suggest you to use 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT (will be final in few days)

Comment: I am using 1.3.0. Now I changed to 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT but it is still not working. I get the same as with 1.3.0.

Comment: Have you used latest snapshot: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Yes. I have just downloaded it just to test if Maven was not finding the right one, but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Hey Lucia, you were right. With new BP we don't have anymore out and in but out_* and in_*. These functions must support the new shape. Hope to fix it in few hours.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: Done. Can you retry with latest snapshot please?

Comment: I have tried now with `orientdb-1.4.0-20130502.170215-187` and I got `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: No function for name SHORTESTPATH, available names are : (...)`.

Comment: You've to use the GraphEdition because right now all the graph algo are in the graph-db module. Do: "git clone https://github.com/nuvolabase/blueprints.git", then "cd blueprints", then "mvn clean install". You will have a fresh BP in your system. I suggest you to import the projects "blueprints-orient-graph" in your IDE to work with the snapshot. However in few days will be final.

Comment: I am not using git for my project and I use Eclipse's m2e. I tried changing my `blueprints-orient-graph` to version `2.4.0-SNAPSHOT` (I was using 2.3.0 before) in pom.xml and also downloading blueprints-orient-graph-2.4.0-20130428.201000-9.jar from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blueprints-orient-graph/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/. I even tried changing `com.tinkerpop.gremlin` `gremlin-java` to version `2.4.0-SNAPSHOT`. Unfortunately, none of them worked.

Comment: You could get last snapshot GraphEd 1.4.0 from: http://www.orientdb.org/download.htm

Comment: This one https://s3.amazonaws.com/orientdb/releases/orientdb-graphed-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz didn't work.

Comment: I retried and this time I could download it, add all libs in Eclipse and now it doesn't fail but I am still getting the same results that I put above (`[#-2:1 v0]` and `[#-2:0 v0]`).

Comment: Can you send us the db as json or the set of commands to recreate it?

Comment: Lucia, your graphdb has no edges. That's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it didn't work how dante or Lvca explained it:

```
select flatten(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(#12:0,#12:2,'BOTH')
```

This lead to errors in the console or to no records returned in the OrientDB Studio.

Instead, when I used an alias for the function result, it worked finally. So maybe try out this form:

```
select flatten(sp) from (select shortestPath(#12:0,#15:2,'BOTH') as sp)
```

(Note. I'm using v1.7.4)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(" + firstVertex + ", " + secondVertex + "))
```

You will receive vertices.

Comment: My question was about edges, not vertices.