# OrientDB: Edges in shortestPath

Tags: graph-theory, orientdb, shortest-path

My Graph Looks like this:

```
A --1--> B --2--> C --3--> D

|
4
|
V

E
```

I want to get the shortest paths from A to D. But I do not want the vertices but the edges that make up the path.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222813/get-visited-edges-in-orientdbs-shortestpath) I ended up with:

```
 select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(A, D).outE())
```

But the result does not only contain the correct answers 1, 2, 3 but also 4, so all outgoing edges from the vertices that make up the path.

- How could I get only the edges that make up the shortest path?
- What if there are several shortest paths, how can I get all of them?

It would be cool if I could select shortestpath or dijkstra as a traversal strategy. IMO this is where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer, this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794694/orientdb-get-edges-with-shortestpath/72171179#72171179), I have posted a possible solution using SQL along with explanation.

In brief, the SQL is :

```
SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE * FROM #51:0 WHILE 
                (@this INSTANCEOF V AND @rid IN (SELECT shortestPath(#51:0, #60:40).asList())) OR 
                (@this INSTANCEOF E AND (@this.in IN (SELECT shortestPath(#51:0, #60:40).asList()))) );
```

Answer (score -1):

OrientDB already has dijkstra function. Howerver to filter only the edges do:

```
select from (select expand( shortestPath(A, D) ) ) where @this instanceof 'E'
```

Comment: Doing the expansion like you suggest returns 0 records. the expansion like this works: `select from (select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(#13:0, #13:2))) where @this instanceof 'E'` however with the where clause it returns 0 records. I am using `orientdb-community-2.0-rc1` but that should not matter?!

Comment: Using 2.1.7-SNAPSHOT, `select expand(shortestpath(...))` only returns vertices.

Comment: @pat  is right, A and D should replaced with nodes IDs like pat replies.
tnx