# OrientDB all paths between two nodes

Tags: search, path, orientdb

@OrientDB 2.1.12 :

I want to find ALL possible PATHS of ANY length between two nodes considering navigation by OUT edges only.

I am using shortestPath() but it returns only one path. I searched a lot and I couldn’t find a native class which does this in OrientDB. I am already using non-native class. However, it is not efficient enough. Here some of the shortespath code:

```
s = " select expand( shortestpath(" + first_vertex.getId() + ", " + second_vertex.getId() + ", "+ direction +"))";
for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) g.command(new OCommandSQL(s)).execute()){ 

            . . . 
. . . 

    }
```

Is there any native solution in OrientDB as it is the case in Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
    import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
    import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

    public class AllPaths {

        private boolean stop=false;
        private Vertex vertexFrom=null;
        private List<Vertex> vertexPreviousStep=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        private List<Vertex> vertexCurrently=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        private List<List<Vertex>> paths=new ArrayList<List<Vertex>>();
        private OrientGraph g;

        public AllPaths(OrientGraph g) {
            this.g=g;
        } 

        protected List<List<Vertex>> getPaths(String ridFrom, String ridTo) {
            if(!check(ridFrom,ridTo))
                return paths;
            vertexPreviousStep.add(vertexFrom);
            List<Vertex> p=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
            p.add(vertexFrom);
            paths.add(p);
            int step=1;
            do{
                stop=false;
                for(Vertex v: vertexPreviousStep){
                    List<Vertex> toAdd=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                    Iterable<Vertex> nodes = (Iterable<Vertex>) v.getVertices(Direction.OUT);
                    for(Vertex v1:nodes){
                        toAdd.add(v1);
                        if(!v1.getId().toString().equals(ridTo))  
                            vertexCurrently.add(v1);
                    }
                    if(toAdd.size()!=0)
                        setPaths(v,toAdd,step);
                }
                change();
                step++;
            }while(stop==true);
            return cleanPaths(ridTo);
        }

        private boolean check(String ridFrom,String ridTo) {
            boolean findFrom=false,findTo=false;
            for(Vertex v:g.getVertices()){
                if(v.getId().toString().equals(ridFrom)){
                    findFrom=true;
                    vertexFrom=v;
                }
                else if(v.getId().toString().equals(ridTo))
                    findTo=true;
            }
            if(findFrom==false || findTo==false)
                return false; 
            return true;
        }

        public void change(){
            vertexPreviousStep.clear();
            for(Vertex v:vertexCurrently)
                vertexPreviousStep.add(v);
            vertexCurrently.clear();
        }

        private void setPaths(Vertex previousVertex,List<Vertex> toAdd,int step) {
            for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++){
                List<Vertex> list=paths.get(i);
                Vertex last=list.get(list.size()-1);
                if(last.getId().toString().equals(previousVertex.getId().toString()) && list.size()==step){  
                    int j=0;
                    for(Vertex v1:toAdd){
                        boolean vertexFound=false;
                        for(Vertex v2:list){
                            if(v2.getId().toString().equals(v1.getId().toString()))
                                vertexFound=true;   
                        }
                        if(vertexFound==false){
                            List<Vertex> listVertex=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                            for(Vertex p:list)
                                listVertex.add(p);
                            listVertex.add(v1);
                            if(j==0){
                                stop=true;
                                paths.set(i,listVertex);
                                j++;
                            }
                            else
                                paths.add(listVertex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }

        public List<List<Vertex>> cleanPaths(String ridTo){
            for(int i=0;i<paths.size();i++){
                List<Vertex> list=paths.get(i);
                if(!list.get(list.size()-1).getId().toString().equals(ridTo)){
                    paths.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return paths;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/MyDb"); 
            AllPaths paths=new AllPaths(g);
            System.out.println(paths.getPaths("#9:0", "#9:8"));

        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class Main {

    private boolean stop=false;
    private List<Vertex> visitedNodesPreviousStep=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    private List<Vertex> visitedNodeCurrently=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    private List<List<Vertex>> path_vertex=new ArrayList<List<Vertex>>();
    private List<List<Edge>> path_edges=new ArrayList<List<Edge>>();
    private OrientGraph g;
    int step=0;

    public Main(OrientGraph g) {
        this.g=g;
    }

    protected List<List<Object>> getDistance(String starting_rid, String ending_rid,int depth) {

        Vertex starting_node=g.getVertex(starting_rid);
        Vertex ending_node=g.getVertex(ending_rid);

        visitedNodesPreviousStep.add(starting_node);

        List<Vertex> p1=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        p1.add(starting_node);
        path_vertex.add(p1);

        step=1;
        boolean found_node_to_be_added=false;
        do{
            stop=false;
            found_node_to_be_added=false;
            for(Vertex v: visitedNodesPreviousStep){
                List<Edge> edges_to_be_added=new ArrayList<Edge>();
                List<Vertex> nodes_to_be_added=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                Iterable<Edge> it_edge = (Iterable<Edge>) v.getEdges(Direction.OUT);
                for(Edge e1:it_edge){
                    Vertex v1=e1.getVertex(Direction.IN);
                    edges_to_be_added.add(e1);
                    nodes_to_be_added.add(v1);
                    String rid=v1.getId().toString();
                    if(!rid.equals(ending_rid)){  // checking the current @rid isn't the ending
                        visitedNodeCurrently.add(v1);
                    }
                    else{   // ending node found
                        setPathFoundList(v,ending_node,step,e1);
                        //stop=true;
                    }
                }
                if(nodes_to_be_added.size()!=0 && stop==false){
                    found_node_to_be_added=true;
                    setpath_vertex(v,nodes_to_be_added,edges_to_be_added);
                }
            }
            if(found_node_to_be_added==false){
                stop=true;
            }
            //System.out.println("step =  " + step +  "  " +path_vertex);
            change();

            step++;
        }while(stop==false && step<depth);
        clean_vertex_path(ending_node);
        return getShortestPathList();
    }

    public void change(){
        visitedNodesPreviousStep.clear();
        for(Vertex v:visitedNodeCurrently)
            visitedNodesPreviousStep.add(v);
        visitedNodeCurrently.clear();
    }

    private void setPathFoundList(Vertex node,Vertex ending_node,int step,Edge edge){
        for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
            List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
            Vertex last=path.get(path.size()-1);
            if(last.getId().equals(node.getId()) && path.size()==step){
                path.add(ending_node);
                List<Edge> edgesPath=path_edges.get(i);
                edgesPath.add(edge);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setpath_vertex(Vertex node,List<Vertex> nodes_to_be_added,List<Edge> edges_to_be_added) {
        for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
            List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
            Vertex last=path.get(path.size()-1);
            if(last.getId().equals(node.getId())){
                int j=0;
                for(int h=0;h<nodes_to_be_added.size();h++){
                    boolean name_present=false;
                    for(Vertex p:path){
                        if(p.getId().equals(nodes_to_be_added.get(h).getId()))
                            name_present=true;
                    }
                    if(name_present==false){
                        List<Vertex> p2=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
                        for(Vertex p:path)
                            p2.add(p);
                        p2.add(nodes_to_be_added.get(h));
                        List<Edge> e2=new ArrayList<Edge>();
                        if(step==1){
                            e2.add(edges_to_be_added.get(h));
                        }
                        else{
                            List<Edge> edgesPath=path_edges.get(i);
                            for(Edge p1:edgesPath)
                                e2.add(p1);
                            e2.add(edges_to_be_added.get(h));
                        }
                        if(j==0){
                            path_vertex.set(i, p2);
                            if(step==1){
                                path_edges.add(i, e2);
                            }
                            else{
                                path_edges.set(i, e2);
                            }
                            j++;
                        }
                        else{
                            path_vertex.add(p2);
                            path_edges.add(e2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clean_vertex_path(Vertex ending_node_name){
        for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
            List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
            if(!path.get(path.size()-1).getId().equals(ending_node_name.getId())){
                path_vertex.remove(i);
                path_edges.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<List<Object>> getShortestPathList(){
        List<List<Object>> resultList=new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        if(path_vertex.size()==0)
            return new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
                List<Object> result=new ArrayList<Object>();
                List<Vertex> path2= path_vertex.get(i);
                List<Edge> edges2= path_edges.get(i);
                for(int k=0;k<path2.size();k++){
                    result.add(path2.get(k));
                    if(k!=path2.size()-1)
                        result.add(edges2.get(k));
                }
                resultList.add(result);
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String remote="remote:localhost/";
        String DBname="ShortestPath";
        String currentPath=remote+DBname;

        OServerAdmin serverAdmin;
        try {
            serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(currentPath).connect("root", "root");
            if(serverAdmin.existsDatabase()){

                OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(currentPath);
                Main shortest2 = new Main(g);
                System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH " + shortest2.getDistance("#9:0","#9:8",5));

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. I already used your code but the problem it is really very slow at least comparing to Neo4j.

Comment: @Questioner How much is the difference in speed?

Comment: There is no such function in OrientDB, but you could extend the shortestPath() and avoid to return at the first occurrence, but continuing up to X items found.

Answer (score 0):

@ Lvca and @ Alessandro

I used this code by "LucaS" [OrientDB get Edges with shortestPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794694/orientdb-get-edges-with-shortestpath)

I find it efficient and useful. What you think about? It retrieves all paths between two nodes. How I can determine the search depth to be for example of depth 2,3, 4 etc.?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OServerAdmin;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class myClass {

private boolean stop=false;
private List<Vertex> visitedNodesPreviousStep=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
private List<Vertex> visitedNodeCurrently=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
private List<List<Vertex>> path_vertex=new ArrayList<List<Vertex>>();
private List<List<Edge>> path_edges=new ArrayList<List<Edge>>();
private OrientGraph g;
int step=0;

public myClass(OrientGraph g) {
this.g=g;
}

protected List<Object> getDistance(String starting_rid, String ending_rid) {

Vertex starting_node=g.getVertex(starting_rid);
Vertex ending_node=g.getVertex(ending_rid);

visitedNodesPreviousStep.add(starting_node);

List<Vertex> p1=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
p1.add(starting_node);
path_vertex.add(p1);

step=1;
boolean found_node_to_be_added=false;
do{
stop=false;
found_node_to_be_added=false;
for(Vertex v: visitedNodesPreviousStep){
List<Edge> edges_to_be_added=new ArrayList<Edge>();
List<Vertex> nodes_to_be_added=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
Iterable<Edge> it_edge = (Iterable<Edge>) v.getEdges(Direction.OUT);
for(Edge e1:it_edge){
Vertex v1=e1.getVertex(Direction.IN);
edges_to_be_added.add(e1);
nodes_to_be_added.add(v1);
String rid=v1.getId().toString();
if(!rid.equals(ending_rid)){  // checking the current @rid isn't the ending
visitedNodeCurrently.add(v1);
}
else{   // ending node found
setPathFoundList(v,ending_node,step,e1);
stop=true;
}
}
if(nodes_to_be_added.size()!=0 && stop==false){
found_node_to_be_added=true;
setpath_vertex(v,nodes_to_be_added,edges_to_be_added);
}
}
if(found_node_to_be_added==false){
stop=true;
}
System.out.println("step =  " + step +  "  " +path_vertex);
change();

step++;
}while(stop==false);
clean_vertex_path(ending_node);
return getShortestPathList();
}

public void change(){
visitedNodesPreviousStep.clear();
for(Vertex v:visitedNodeCurrently)
visitedNodesPreviousStep.add(v);
visitedNodeCurrently.clear();
}

private void setPathFoundList(Vertex node,Vertex ending_node,int step,Edge edge){
for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
Vertex last=path.get(path.size()-1);
if(last.getId().equals(node.getId()) && path.size()==step){
path.add(ending_node);
List<Edge> edgesPath=path_edges.get(i);
edgesPath.add(edge);
}
}
}

private void setpath_vertex(Vertex node,List<Vertex> nodes_to_be_added,List<Edge> edges_to_be_added) {
for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
Vertex last=path.get(path.size()-1);
if(last.getId().equals(node.getId())){
int j=0;
for(int h=0;h<nodes_to_be_added.size();h++){
boolean name_present=false;
for(Vertex p:path){
if(p.getId().equals(nodes_to_be_added.get(h).getId()))
name_present=true;
}
if(name_present==false){
List<Vertex> p2=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
for(Vertex p:path)
p2.add(p);
p2.add(nodes_to_be_added.get(h));
List<Edge> e2=new ArrayList<Edge>();
if(step==1){
e2.add(edges_to_be_added.get(h));
}
else{
List<Edge> edgesPath=path_edges.get(i);
for(Edge p1:edgesPath)
e2.add(p1);
e2.add(edges_to_be_added.get(h));
}
if(j==0){
path_vertex.set(i, p2);
if(step==1){
path_edges.add(i, e2);
}
else{
path_edges.set(i, e2);
}
j++;
}
else{
path_vertex.add(p2);
path_edges.add(e2);
}
}
}
}
}
}

public void clean_vertex_path(Vertex ending_node_name){
for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(i);
if(!path.get(path.size()-1).getId().equals(ending_node_name.getId())){
path_vertex.remove(i);
path_edges.remove(i);
i--;
}
}
}

public List<Object> getShortestPathList(){
List<Object> result=new ArrayList<Object>();
if(path_vertex.size()==0)
return new ArrayList<Object>();
else{
List<Vertex> path=path_vertex.get(0);
int min_size= path.size();
for(int i=0;i<path_vertex.size();i++){
if(path_vertex.get(i).size()<=min_size){
List<Vertex> path2= path_vertex.get(i);
List<Edge> edges2= path_edges.get(i);
for(int k=0;k<path2.size();k++){
result.add(path2.get(k));
if(k!=path2.size()-1)
result.add(edges2.get(k));
}
}
}
}
return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String remote="remote:localhost/";
String DBname="Stack36794694";
String currentPath=remote+DBname;

OServerAdmin serverAdmin;
try {
serverAdmin = new OServerAdmin(currentPath).connect("root", "root");
if(serverAdmin.existsDatabase()){

OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(currentPath);
myClass shortest2 = new myClass(g);
System.out.println("SHORTEST PATH " + shortest2.getDistance("#9:0","#9:5"));

}
}
catch(Exception e){
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer by modifying the code by LucaS